# is it possible to configure universal windows platform(UWP) tools in visual studio 2015?

Tags: uwp

I have tried to follow steps,get WinRT and Universal Apps controls in visual studio tool box, we will make the below registry entries and put value as below and maintaining the assemblies in below folder structure..

steps:

Registry Entry (location) :

```
" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Sample Product for WinRT XAML\X.X.X.X"
```

Value  :

```
      "Assemblies(.dll) shipped path" (Which having toolbox controls)
```

winRT platform SDK folder location :

```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company Name\ProductName\X.X.X.X\WinRT\8.1\SDK"
```

Assemblies Folder Structure:

```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company Name\ProductName\X.X.X.X\WinRT\8.1\SDK\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\"
```

But doing the same like this for Universal Windows Apps controls, toolbox is not configured. For this we have created registry entry as below and maintaining the same assemblies folder structure.

Universal Windows Registry Entry:

```
 "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0\ExtensionSDKs\Sample Product for Universal Windows App Platform\X.X.X.X"
```

Could anyone please suggest the proper way to configure the Universal Windows controls(.dll) in Visual Studio 2015 toolbox ?

Thanks,

Comment: I have never used the registry to add controls to the toolbox.  I would recommend right clicking on the toolbox and browsing to the location of the controls.  If the default controls are missing I would try right clicking on the toolbox and select reset toolbox